# Does anyone know why thunderbird is suddently asking for my gmail password every day?

Tags: email, thunderbird, gmail

All of a sudden, after a routine software update, thunderbird is asking me for my gmail password once per day.  Does anyone know if this is from the gmail side or the thunderbird side?  It's only a little bit annoying, but it's a change from previous behavior.

This window pops up:
[image]

Comment: Does your Google account show that you granted access to Thunderbird in your Third-Party apps (in Security)?

Comment: @DaveStSomeWhere yes it does.  Every time thunderbird give me the popup and I duly log in, I also get an email saying that gmail granted access to thunderbird.

Comment: OK, sounds like it's on the TB side. Do you see a popup or check box to have TB manage/save that password(It's been a while since I saw it but should be obvious)

Comment: @DaveStSomeWhere nowhere obvious, though I haven't looked past the "here be dagrons" warning in the config menu

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using an application password. Most of the time the session is created when you login, to prevent you from keeping an open client session. Depends on the provider. But, try the app password.